# How can i join various bones that move different parts of the rig into one?

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones, vertices

I have a rig from a game, and among all the bones of the armature, there are some duplicate bones that move different parts of a body part, but should be just one bone, how can I join them?
For example, for the arm, there are three different bones, and every bone moves a different part of the arm, while it should be just one bone for it.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Seems like those bones should be parented to each one higher up the arm (rigging basics), or they are and you’re moving them when they’re meant to be rotated.

Comment: they all have the same name, but 001, 002, so they should be just one bone, i dont know how to merge them into one single bone

Comment: No, no. You’re thinking of this completely wrong. Please, look up an armature/rigging tutorial. You do NOT want to merge them all into one bone, or the model will be restricted to snake-like curve poses with no finger articulation at all.

Answer (score 0):

### About this model

I think your blend file was imported into Blender with the wrong axis settings from in another file format one, for example fbx.
It looks like someone then split the original armature into multiple pieces and changed the parenting relationship by adding some bones.
Unfortunately, the last remodel is half-finished.
It is best way to edit the orientation of the bones, delete any bones that were added later and re-parent them.

### Policy

For looking like a single bone I will show you how to edit the parenting of some bones and change Visible Layers the armature.
Because it is difficult to explain best method in detail to an unfamiliar person.

### Modify

In the explanations below, I often switch to pose mode to make it easier to select overlapping bones.
Basically, you can do it only in edit mode.

1. **Initial setting:**

- Select mod armature object
- Select the first and third button of View Layers to show the hidden bones associated with the arms.
- To Pose mode
- Rotate or move the four bones in the figure so that they do not overlap
  [image]

2. **Deleting unused bones:**

- Select the two bones, *Bip001 LUpArmTwist.001* and *Bip001 LUpArmTwist1.001*, in Pose mode
- Delete then in Edit mode

3. **Reparenting:**

- Select the 5 bones in Figure 2. However, the *Bip001 L UpperArm* bone must be selected and activated last.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> with Keep Offseet in Edit mode
  [image]

4. **Change Visible Layer:**

- In Pose mode
- Select the 4 bones **except for** ***Bip001 L UpperArm*** bone from the previous ones
- Press <kbd>M</kbd> and select an empty layer
- Press <kbd>M</kbd> and select the 3rd layer

5. **Post-processing:**

- Menu > Pose >  Clear Transform All
- Select only the first visible layer
  [image]